# rvest html_table() use second row as header

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from a table on fbref however the tables contain two headers with the subheader being incorporated into the first row of data. Does anyone know how to skip the first line and use the second line as the table header so that data types can be maintained? Here is my code below.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

team_link = "https://fbref.com/en/squads/cff3d9bb/Chelsea-Stats-All-Competitions"
team_page = read_html(team_link)

shooting_table = team_page %>% html_nodes("#all_stats_shooting") %>%
  html_table()

shooting_table = shooting_table[[1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `janitor` package

```
library(janitor)

shooting_table %>%
  row_to_names(1)
```

Which gives us:

```
# A tibble: 28 × 23
   Player     Nation Pos   Age   `90s` Gls   Sh    SoT   `SoT%` `Sh/90` `SoT/90` `G/Sh` `G/SoT` Dist  FK    PK   
   <chr>      <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 Edouard M… sn SEN GK    29    34.0  0     0     0     ""     0.00    0.00     ""     ""      ""    0     0    
 2 Antonio R… de GER DF    28    33.7  3     48    13    "27.1" 1.42    0.39     "0.06" "0.23"  "19.… 0     0    
 3 Thiago Si… br BRA DF    36    29.4  3     18    5     "27.8" 0.61    0.17     "0.17" "0.60"  "10.… 0     0    
 4 Mason Mou… eng E… MF,FW 22    26.3  11    75    27    "36.0" 2.86    1.03     "0.13" "0.37"  "17.… 6     1
```